# Force Ansible to reevaluate contents of an imported playbook as a task after main playbook that does the importing has started

Tags: ansible

Please consider the following scenario. An Ansible playbook, that uses a serries of `ansible.builtin.import_playbook` module calls, to chain other ansible playbooks together. We'll call this playbook `main.yaml`

```
...

- name: Import Ansible Playbook A
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook_a.yaml

- name: Import Ansible Playbook B
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook_b.yaml

...
```

My `playbook_a.yaml` calls a bash script, that eventually makes some changes in `playbook_b.yaml` using sed. In this current iteration,  once `main.yaml` is started, my understanding is it reads the contents of all the files, including those imported via the `ansible.builtin.import_playbook` module, at the start of the playbook run, so any changes introduced into of those files after the start are not considered and are ignored. Essentially it plays them as they were, and not as they have become during the play.

My question is, is there a way for me to force `main.yaml` to reevaluate the conets of `playbook_b.yaml`, perhaps by adding another task between the import of `playbook_a.yaml` and `playbook_b.yaml` that would accomplish this?

Obviously I can run `playbook_a.yaml` seperatly, before starting `main.yaml` to avoid this issue, but my hope is to contain it all in one play.

TIA

Comment: ```My playbook_a.yaml calls a bash script, that eventually makes some changes in playbook_b.yaml using sed```

what sort of changes are you doing? are you modifying the `playbook_b.yaml` file, or setting a variable?

Comment: The bash script will sed the value of password in the following task. Sorry it looks ugly in the comment. @CarlosMonroyNieblas
 

`- name: Change Password /n
    user: /n
        name: foo /n
        password: "bar_123" /n
        update_password: always /n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I have come up with two solutions that accomplish what I was hoping to accomplish. One is more of a a hacky solution and the other more of a proper Ansible solution.

1. Hacky Solution

Back in the `main.yaml`, instead of importing `playbook_b.yaml` directly, we import a new playbook, let's call it `playbook_c.yaml`,

```
...

- name: Import Ansible Playbook A
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook_a.yaml

- name: Import Ansible Playbook C
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook_c.yaml

...
```

which in turn only contains the following task:

```
...

  tasks:
 1. name: Call Playbook B
    ansible.builtin.shell: ansible-playbook playbook_b.yaml
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
    register: call_playbook_b
    changed_when: call_playbook_b != 0
```

Since ansible will not know any information regading `playbook_b.yaml` until `playbook_c.yaml` calls it using a bash command of `ansible-playbook playbook_b.yaml`, any changes introduced into `playbook_b.yaml` by `playbook_a.yaml` will be respected at the time the playbook is called. This feels cheeky but it works, with one major drawback, we don't get to see the output of `playbook_b.yaml`. We only see the output of `playbook_a.yaml` and `playbook_c.yaml` when we run `main.yaml`

2. Proper Solution

We leave our `main.yaml` as is

```
...

- name: Import Ansible Playbook A
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook_a.yaml

- name: Import Ansible Playbook B
  ansible.builtin.import_playbook: playbook_B.yaml

...
```

but modify the bash script called by `playbook_a.yaml` to make the sed changes not into `playbook_b.yaml` directly, but into the inventory file described in `ansible.cfg`, essentially adding a variable to the host(s) that `playbook_b.yaml` is playing against, like a dynamic inventory file. Then we add a `pre_tasks` to `playbook_b.yaml` before the `tasks` section, like so

```
...
  pre_tasks:
  - name: Refresh Inventory File
    ansible.builtin.meta: refresh_inventory

  tasks:
...
```

forcing ansible to reread the inventory file taking into the account the new values of the variables that were seded by the bash script called by `playbook_a.yaml`. Afterwards the variables can easily be referenced in `playbook_b.yaml` and they will take the latest value introduced after the start of `main.yaml` and `playbook_a.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to reread imported playbooks. Instead, you can modify included tasks in the imported playbooks. For example, given the tree

```bash
shell:> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb_a.yml
├── pb_b.yml
├── pb.yml
├── tasks
│   ├── a_tasks.yml
│   └── b_tasks.yml
└── templates
    ├── tasks_1.yml.j2
    └── tasks_2.yml.j2
```

Create the playbooks

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    playbook_updates:
      - {dest: tasks/a_tasks.yml, template: tasks_1.yml.j2}
      - {dest: tasks/b_tasks.yml, template: tasks_2.yml.j2}

  tasks:
    - name: Update playbooks
      template:
        src: "{{ item.template }}"
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ item.dest }}"
      loop: "{{ playbook_updates }}"

- import_playbook: pb_a.yml
- import_playbook: pb_b.yml

shell> cat pb_a.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: tasks/a_tasks.yml

shell> cat pb_b.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: tasks/b_tasks.yml
```

The first play updates the tasks in the imported playbooks according to the list *playbook_updates*. Create the templates, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat templates/tasks_1.yml.j2 
- debug:
    msg: tasks 1
shell> cat templates/tasks_2.yml.j2 
- debug:
    msg: tasks 2
```

Then, the playbook gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************

TASK [Update playbooks] *********************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'dest': 'tasks/a_tasks.yml', 'template': 'tasks_1.yml.j2'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'dest': 'tasks/b_tasks.yml', 'template': 'tasks_2.yml.j2'})

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] ************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-100/tasks/a_tasks.yml for localhost

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: tasks 1

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] ************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-100/tasks/b_tasks.yml for localhost

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: tasks 2

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can modify the included tasks by modifying the templates and variables.